# Displaying four figure at the top of the same page

Tags: graphics, wide-image

I'm placing four figures in my thesis. I want to make them all at the top of the same page in one figure with one comment like the next left image. Instead, they are displaying under each other in one page as four figures like the right section of the image! [image]
could any one help me to do it?

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN3.pdf}
\caption[PN3]{(a)}
\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN4.pdf}
\caption[PN4]{(b)}
\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN5.pdf}
\caption[PN5]{(c)}
\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN6.pdf}
\caption[PN6]{(d)}
\label{fig: 2.2}
\end{figure}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Net is not enabled because multiplicity of read arc $<$ 2
\item Net is not enabled C $>$1
\item The net is enabled
\item The net of (c) after firing.
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN3.pdf}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN4.pdf}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN5.pdf}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN6.pdf}}

\medskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Net is not enabled because multiplicity of read arc $<$ 2
\item Net is not enabled C $>$1
\item The net is enabled
\item The net of (c) after firing.
\end{enumerate*}
\end{minipage}
\caption{}
\label{fig: 2.2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-4]
    \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
\subfloat[Net is not enabled because multiplicity of read arc $<2$] {\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN3.pdf}}\hfil
\subfloat[Net is not enabled C $>1$] {\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN4.pdf}}

\subfloat[The net is enabled]{\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN5.pdf}}\hfil
\subfloat[The net of (c) after firing]{\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN6.pdf}}
\caption{}
\label{fig: 2.2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The first case:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The second case:

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Edit:**
I wonder, why you for `\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN6.pdf}` use options `scale=1, angle=0` which nothing change on included image (not scale nor rotate image) and use image type extension. Extension is surplus, since `graphicx` find and handle image files with supported formats (`.pdf`, `.png` and `.jpg`) without you declare them. Modern installations of LaTeX can use `.eps` files as well, but indirectly. Of course, your images files had to be in subdirectory `Files` in directory where you have your document.

Therefore above MWE can be written as (considered only the first part of above MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document option "demo" had to be deleted
\usepackage[labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{Files/PN3}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{Files/PN4}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{Files/PN5}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{Files/PN6}}

\medskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Net is not enabled because multiplicity of read arc $<$ 2
\item Net is not enabled C $>$1
\item The net is enabled
\item The net of (c) after firing.
\end{enumerate*}
\end{minipage}
\caption{}
\label{fig: 2.2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank younow i get it but why they appear as black images??

Comment: @Sama_science, image is drawn by option `demo` of `graphicx` package. In real document just delete this option and use only `\usepackage{graphicx}` and you will see your original images (which I haven't and consequently I use `demo`).

Comment: do you have any idea why i'm keeping have this message"LaTeX Warning: File `Files/PN3.pdf' not found on input line 14.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Files/PN3.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.                                   
l.14 ...graphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN3.pdf}}
                                                  \hfil ?

Comment: @Sama_science, error tell, that picture `PN3.pdf` is not on given path. You should check if it is there (with extension `.pdf`). By the way, extensions `.pdf` in figure names in the code is better to omit, i.e. instead of `\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN3.pdf}˙` is sufficient to use `\includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{Files/PN3}`:

Comment: I'm sure it exsists inside the file with pdf type that's why i'm confused!!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see in your file systems and check if image files are in subdirectory "Files" or is somewhere some spelling error. For sure the code in my MWE is error free (tested, but in my test system).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \subcaptionbox{A picture.\label{Picture}}[0.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}} &
    \subcaptionbox{Picture A.\label{PictureA}}[0.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}} \\
    \subcaptionbox{Picture B.\label{PictureB}}[0.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}} &
    \subcaptionbox{Picture C.\label{PictureC}}[0.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Test of four pictures.\label{fig:Four}}
\end{figure}

In Figure~\ref{fig:Four} there are four picture, where Figure~\ref{Picture} is one of them. 
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]